# Wrong place for hyperref link in scaled tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, scaling

I have a TikZ picture with a node containing a minipage with an itemize environment; each item is a hyperref to other sections of the document.

When scaling the image (for example with `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape]` I've a strange behavior: links in itemize are not in the right place: they present a somewhat vertical offset, as if they don't scale as the rest of image.

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Here something interesting\label{text:interesting-one}
\newpage

Here something interesting, too\label{text:interesting-two}
\newpage

and here there are very very interesting stuff\label{text:interesting-three}
\newpage

\newpage
Now the problem: links rectangles have some offset, making links unusable in case of long itemize

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape]
\node at (0,0) (mynode) {
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-one]{First link}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-two]{Second link}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-three]{Third link}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-one]{First link again}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-two]{Second link again}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-three]{Third link again}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here a snapshot of the problem

[image: hyperref offset in scaled TikZ picture]

Note: This is evident using the default settings of `hyperref` package, which draws the red rectangle around links, but it took me some time to found it when only the text is coloured, i.e. when using `\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}`

Comment: A bug in `tikz`, it does not use the proper interface of pdfTeX for scaling (`\pdfsave`, `\pdfsetmatrix`, `\pdfrestore`).

Comment: FWIW, if you remove the pdftex, then your example works in xelatex or tectonic out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be honest, it looks like you are looking for trouble by nesting all the problematic things into one place :) Don't use `[pdftex]` option for `hyperref` it's smart enough to decide. Also use `\tikzmark` for marking the points where you need rectangle around or use [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed) or something similar to frame it. Otherwise, you need to make sure that everything communicates with each other, no matter what which looks tedious and unnecessary.

An alternative

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

Here something interesting\label{text:interesting-one}
\newpage

Here something interesting, too\label{text:interesting-two}
\newpage

and here there are very very interesting stuff\label{text:interesting-three}
\newpage

\newpage
Now the problem: links rectangles have some offset, making links unusable in case of long itemize

\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-one]{First link}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-two]{Second link}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-three]{Third link}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-one]{First link again}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-two]{Second link again}
\item \hyperref[text:interesting-three]{Third link again}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really don't need frame around link, it is only a way to clearly show the problem. I need tikzpicture, because the itemize is in a 'legend' node in a big orgchart, thats why I've put it into my MWE. Anyway, your code works well: `\scalebox{.7}{
\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture} }`. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

### Fixing `pgf`

pdfTeX does not analyze the contents of `\pdfliteral`. Therefore it does not know the operators that might affect the current transfer matrix (save/restore/set matrix). Instead `\pdfsave`, `\pdfrestore`, `\pdfsetmatrix` should be used. Then pdfTeX can calculate the current transfer matrix and fix the rectangles for anchors and links.

Outdated:

<sub>I have written a patch for `pgf` that supports transformations (rotate/scale, no translate)
via `\pdfsetmatrix` instead of `\pdfliteral`. The patch is added to package `hopgf` v1.1,
currently available [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/hopgf-1.1.pdf) and available on CTAN with the next update of my bundle.</sub>

<sub>The patch redefines `\pgssys@invoke` and scans the argument for
`q` (save), `Q` (restore), and `cm` (set current matrix) operators and replaces them with
`\pdfsave`, `\pdfrestore`, or `\pdfsetmatrix`.
The latter case only happens, if the translate coordinates are zero.
Primitive `\pdfsetmatrix` does not support translation, because
this can already be achieved by TeX, independently from the 
output driver.</sub>

In the meantime I have removed the patch, because it could not address all issues. The main problem is that the low level interfaces does not match: `pgf` operates on the full transfer matrix including translations, whereas `\pdfsetmatrix` does not support translations. Translations with TeX require boxes and that the contents of the material is available.

### Workaround via `graphics/graphicx`:

`pdftex.def`, the driver file for the package `graphics`, uses `\pdfsetmatrix` for rotating and scaling. Thus as workaround `\scalebox` and `\rotatebox` can be used for transformations (see cbe's comment to percusse's answer).

Comment: Can you give a link to your real `hopgf` package (instead of its documentation)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit See section `Installation` how to get the package.

Comment: I realize that I have many scaled `tikzpicture` with `hyperref` inside, spanned across several documents, so I'm going to use your patch (as soon as it will be available) to definitively fix the issue. In the meanwhile, percusse's answer is a very useful workaround.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek `hopgf.dtx` is not on cpan and `hopgf.sty` is not in `oberdiek.tds.zip`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, as I said it is not yet on CTAN (2012-12-16). You can either follow the instructions in the PDF file in subsection "4.5 Details for the interested" or wait until the next bundle update (perhaps next week).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks. I found `hopgf.dtx` joined to the documentation.