# Hyperlinks in rotated TikZ nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

I seem to have a problem with hyperreflinks in rotated TikZ nodes: This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \section{Testsection\label{sec:test}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) [draw=blue] {Unrotated node: see Sec.~\ref{sec:test} on p.~\pageref{sec:test}};
    \node at (5,0) [draw=green,rotate=90] {Rotated node: see     Sec.~\ref{sec:test} on p.~\pageref{sec:test}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

leads to the following output:

[image: hyperlinks in (un)rotated nodes]

The problem is that the hyperlinks for the `\ref`'s in the rotated node appear at the unrotated position. Answers to another question ([Wrong place for hyperref link in scaled tikz picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87026/wrong-place-for-hyperref-link-in-scaled-tikz-picture)) suggested wrapping the whole tikzpicture in a `\rotatebox`, which doesn't directly work here since I have both rotated an unrotated nodes. Also, the `\ref`s appear in several larger tikzpictures which would be a pain to rearrange.

Is there some way to solve/circumvent the problem?

Comment: BTW, hyperref likes to be loaded last (although that doesn't appear to be the problem here).

Comment: FWIW, xelatex or tectonic work out of the box for your example.

Comment: Not in lualatex though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Rotating an individual node seems to work, partially; the bounding box of the picture does not work well.</s>
(Based on John Kormlyo comment) Rotating inside node seems to work.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \section{Test section\label{sec:test}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,5) [draw=blue] {Unrotated node: see Sec.~\ref{sec:test} on p.~\pageref{sec:test}};
    \node at (5,5) [draw=green] {\rotatebox{90}{Rotated node: see {Sec.~\ref{sec:test}} on p.~\pageref{sec:test}    }};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Putting \rotatebox inside the node works better.