# tikzscale does not preserve clickable reference location with hyperref+cleveref

Tags: floats, tikzscale

I am using tikzscale to shrink a tikz figure located in another .tikz file. While the color of the references is preserved, the reference clickable regions are no longer aligned with the text. When I do not scale, the references are properly clickable, but the figure does not scale.

Is there a way to shrink the figure while preserving the clickable regions of the references? MWE and photo below.

MWE:

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}
\label{sec:example}

Sample text.

\begin{figure*}[ht]
% \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mwe.tikz} %% do not resize
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mwe.tikz}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

mwe.tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\large]
\node[draw] (first) {\Cref{sec:example}.};
\node[draw, below right=10cm and 10cm of first] (second) {text};
\node[draw, below right=10cm and 10cm of second] (third) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: mwe]

Comment: the link is clickable for me.

Comment: Yes, but it is no longer aligned with the text.

Comment: Edited the text to clarify.

Comment: you are using `transform shape`, and due to a bug in pgf the link rectangles are then wrong, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87188/2388.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround using `\resizebox` and quitting `tikzscale`, as mentioned in both [@cbe's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87026/wrong-place-for-hyperref-link-in-scaled-tikz-picture/87188#comment187943_87028) and [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87188):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
%\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}\label{sec:example}

Sample text.

\begin{figure*}[ht]
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
      \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\large]
      \node[draw] (first) {\Cref{sec:example}.};
      \node[draw, below right=10cm and 10cm of first] (second) {text};
      \node[draw, below right=10cm and 10cm of second] (third) {text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]