# URL positions getting shifted from the URL reference text after adding page borders

Tags: links, border

I am making my resume on Latex for the first time and had an issue with the placement of links getting shifted upwards after adding page borders.

This is how my links look after I have added the page borders:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Asa1.png

As can be seen, the blue boxes of the links have shifted upwards and do not match with the URL reference texts. Now, this problem is not there when I don't add any page borders:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVJ2w.png

For reference, this is how I am adding the page border:

```
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}


\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
```

Comment: pgf doesn't get well along with links, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87188/2388. Why don't you add the borders simply with e.g. eso-pic and don't shrink the pages?

Comment: Thanks for the info on pgf. I tried using tikz for the border, and while it is a little more tedious, it is serving my purpose well for now.